# Can not update an Id field

Tags: javascript, community, custom-button, opportunity, locking

I'm using the following javascript code to unlock an Opportunity object.

```
Opportunity.PoSa_Platform_Provider__c}{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/25.0/connection.js")}

//Get the URL String
var recordURL = document.URL;
var URLlength = recordURL.length;

//Get the record ID from the URL.
//Id length of Opportunity object is 15
var recordId = recordURL.substring((URLlength - 15), URLlength);
alert("recordId: " + recordId);

//Assuming the name of the locked field is locked__c
var opp = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity");
alert("opp: " + opp);
opp.id = "0067E000003p5ey";
opp.IsPrivate = false;
var result1 = sforce.connection.create([opp]);

if (result1[0].getBoolean("success")) {
alert("Updated the locked field value to " + result1[0].locked__c);
} else {
alert("failed to update " + result1[0]);
}
```

but I get the following message:
"failed to update {errors:{fields:'id', message:'can not specify Id in an insert call', StatusCode:'INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE'}'id:null, success:'false'}"

Could you please advise why it is not possible to update the id field in the javascript code?

Comment: Why have you edited out your code?

Answer (score 1):

Id is a Salesforce native field and it is not updateable. We can't change Id value and we can't update them as well. They are read only for end user.

Every ID in the App is either 15 characters or 18 characters (API). The first 3-digits of the ID are always the Entity ID which can be used to determine the type of the entity. Below is the Entity ID mapping. To use it, get the first 3-digits of the ID and look-up the Entity name in the following table.

For example, for ID: 00D000000000062, you need to lookup "00D" in the table below, which will indicate that it's an Organization ID.

Below is an example of a Contact ID (003D0000001aH2A) on NA1 which has server ID 'D':

003                       D0          000001aH2A

Object ID Prefix    Server ID     Identifier

[Reference Standard Field Record ID Prefix Decoder](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005995&language=)

Answer (score 0):

You just replace this line

```
var result1 = sforce.connection.create([opp]);
```

into

```
var result1 = sforce.connection.update([opp]);
```

When If you have an record Id. you should take update method. Don't try to create method because salesforce Id field is a standard and system generated field. we only have a view permission. It doesn't updatable field in salesforce.